# NSMutableArray values becoming "invalid"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to show a database information in a tableview and then the detailed information in a view my problem is as follow:

I created a `NSMutableArray`: `NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`
Then I populated it form a database `MyObj *obj = [[MyObj alloc]initWithName:idObj];`

When I show the values in the tableview `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method everything goes fine, but when I try to load the same array in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, the values in the arrays are "invalid".

The `NSMutableArray` declaration is as follow:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

Here is the code:

.h file

```
NSMutableArray *antrosArray; 

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *antrosArray;
```

.m file

```
@synthesize antrosArray; 

//filling the array: 

Antro *antro = [[Antro alloc]initWithName:idAntro nombre:aName]; 
[self.antrosArray addObject:antro];
```

my problem is:

when I access the array from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` tableView methods, everything goes ok, but when the user selects a record I tried to read the array in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method and all the values in my array are invalid.

The array is there, and also the object, but the values for the objects are empty, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is cleaning the array.

Comment: There really doesn't seem to be enough information here to answer your question with anything concrete. Post your code.

Comment: Please edit your question to include it. Putting it into a comment doesn't work because it ends up one big block of unreadable text.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to include a description of exactly what you mean by “invalid”.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are defining a second local variable called myArray. What you should do instead is

```
self.myArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

As a matter of fact, you should probably be using -initWithCapacity: instead as well, but that's another matter.

Edit: Thanks Chuck for pointing out my missing autorelease :)

Comment: Actually, it should be either `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]` or one of the convenience constructors, because the setter already claims ownership. Without the release, you get a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution, but I'm still getting invalid values in my array when I access it from another method.   I read some about memory management, and it suggest that my arrays it is been realeased automatically.   I used "retain" to keep the information but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Guillermo: Please edit your question to include a minimal example including Magnus' suggestions but still showing the bug. Without anything concrete to look at, we're stabbing blindly in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Use `retain` during definition as well.